# Mysql - Stored procedure not using the query cache

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have just converted a SQL select statement into a stored procedure

The SQL Statement use select statement takes 
0.4784s to run the first time and 0.0003s after that

The Stored procedure takes 0.4784s to run every time.

I assume the query cache is not been used

How can I rectify this?

A simplified version of the code

```
SELECT * FROM  Venues WHERE  VenueName  = :TheVenue
```

=======

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  GetVenues
(
  TheVenue  VarChar(22)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM  Venues WHERE  VenueName  =   TheVenue 
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MySQL... it is really difficult to get anything within a stored procedure to take advantage of the query cache.  The dev article [A Practical Look at the MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-query-cache.html) discusses this in some detail.  The limitations are also mentioned in the reference documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-operation.html) and on the [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/).

Basically, don't depend on caching of queries executed inside of stored procedures.  It is near impossible to get it to work though [the first reference](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-query-cache.html) does claim that it is possible.  This usually isn't a problem if you are using stored procedures to encapsulate complicated logic.  Most of the problems that I have seen were caused by using stored procedures for very simple queries where a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) would have sufficed.

Comment: I think that stored procedures should benefit more from caching that a sql string - its all back to front.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a dynamic SQL stored procedure, like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetVenues (TheVenue varchar(22)) 
BEGIN 
SET @s = 'SELECT * FROM Venues WHERE VenueName = ?'; 
SET @v = TheVenue;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @v; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
END;
```

No MySQL server by hand to test the syntax, so you might have to tweak it.