# Mysql query vs stored procedure performance

Tags: mysql

I have tried a query on mysql, the query had called other functions.
Then I added the very same query in a stored procedure and then executed the procedure on mysql.
The execution time of the normal query was less by 1 sec than the procedure.
Weren't it supposed to be the opposite because procedures get cached.

Please explain to me if I'm missing something here. I appreciate your knowledge sharing a lot.

Regards

Comment: Needs more info, ideally the query

Comment: show some code, your query and table definitions please.

Comment: Have you tried it the second time around. Also it would be useful for the code for both.

Comment: you may want to chekc this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577316/mysql-stored-procedure-not-using-the-query-cache

Answer (score 0):

Stored  Procedure is parsed and compiled only once when it's first  created in the database while a text query needs to be parsed and compiled every time it's executed. and this is the difference and it's tiny for a limited number of calls.
If you are trying to compare just for a single query, then query is best way to opt, but for large queries, you should use stroed procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for mysql, but for other database engines like Oracle, the queries may be cached and linked to the connection once compiled. Even the data may be cached in fact.

Did you try to launch the query and the stored procedure several times each? It is mandatory to have a correct estimation of the performance.